# JFrame adding Text not working. Two GUI appear

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jlabel

I am trying to create a simple JFrame menu where there is a nice background, which works, along with some text. The text is a bit buggy. Here is how it looks (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZHUe.jpg)

As you can see, only one line of the text appears not the second line.

Along with that. Two GUI's appear when I run the program. One is completley empty, and one looks like the picture above.

Finally I can't use the method   logo.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.NORTH); without getting an error, same with a few others. The two I tested and worked were only .CENTER, and .LEFT.

Any help would be great!

Oh and almost forgot, here's my code :)

```
    package character;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Niknea on 6/28/14.
 */
public class characterSelector extends JFrame{


    JPanel cselectorText;

    JFrame  cselectorButtons;

    JLabel logo, characterName, label;

    JButton previous, next;


    public characterSelector(String title){
        super(title);

        this.createCharacterSelector();

        this.setSize(1920, 1033);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }


    public void createCharacterSelector(){

      try {
            label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/Grass_Background.jpg"))));


            cselectorButtons = new JFrame();

            logo = new JLabel("SoccerKidz [REPLACE W/ COOL LOGO]");

            characterName = new JLabel("<Character Name>");

            logo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));



            logo.setFont(new Font(logo.getFont().getName(), Font.HANGING_BASELINE, 50));

            characterName.setFont(new Font(characterName.getFont().getName(), Font.HANGING_BASELINE, 50));

            cselectorButtons.add(logo);

            cselectorButtons.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            cselectorButtons.setContentPane(label);
            cselectorButtons.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            characterName.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
            characterName.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            cselectorButtons.add(characterName);
          logo.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
          logo.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
            cselectorButtons.add(logo);
            cselectorButtons.pack();
            cselectorButtons.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            cselectorButtons.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again! :)

Comment: You are creating a JFrame from inside a JFrame class. `cselectorButtons = new JFrame();` is inside of `class characterSelector extends JFrame`.

Comment: so how would I go along fixing it? I cant leave it null.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, so a specific answer is impossible. Judging from the fact that you have a JFrame inside a JFrame tells me that your best bet would be to look into creating separate JPanels for the content you want and combine them all into a single JFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, only one line of the text appears not the second line.

You set the layout of `cselectorButtons` to `BorderLayout`. Then you add `JLabel("<Character Name>");`, which is fine. But then you add `JLabel("SoccerKidz [REPLACE W/ COOL LOGO]");`. Here's what's happening. With `BorderLayout`, when you just `add(component)`, generally you want to specify a `BorderLayout.[POSITION]` as the second argument to the `add`. If you don't, every component that you add, without the position specified, will be added the the `BorderLayout.CENTER` implicitly by default. The problem with this is each position can only have *one* component. So in your case, the first label gets kicked out the center, only showing the second one you added.

> Two GUI's appear when I run the program. One is completley empty, and one looks like the picture above.

When look at your code. Your class is a `JFrame` in which you add nothing to, and `this.setVisible(true)`. And also you a `JFrame  cselectorButtons;` in which you *do* add components and also `cselectorButtons.setVisible(true);`. Can you guess which one is the one you're seeing that's not empty. Don't extends `JFrame`. Just use the instance one you currently are using.

> Finally I can't use the method `logo.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.NORTH);` without getting an error.

It doesn't take much to take a look at [the API for JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29). That being said, what makes you think aligning something horizontally, should include an option to position to the north. Doesn't make sense

> - [`public void setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29)
>
>   Sets the alignment of the label's contents along the X axis.
>
>   **Parameters:**
>     `alignment` - One of the following constants defined in SwingConstants: **`LEFT`**, **`CENTER`** (the default for image-only labels), `RIGHT`, `LEADING` (the default for text-only labels) or `TRAILING`.

---

I suggest you take a look at [Layout out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for other possibly layout managers you can use, if `BorderLayout` doesn't suit you. Also keep in mind you can nest different panels with different layout managers to get your desired result. But first you need to learn how they work.

---

**UPDATE**

I made some changes, which works. I'm also looking at your pastebin code, and can't really see any difference. You may want to investigate my code to try and look for differences

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Created by Niknea on 6/28/14.
 */
public class CharacterSelector {

    JPanel cselectorText;
    JFrame cselectorButtons;
    JLabel logo, characterName, label;
    JButton previous, next;

    public CharacterSelector() {
        createCharacterSelector();
    }

    public void createCharacterSelector() {

        try {
            label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass()
                    .getResource("/resources/Grass_Background.jpg"))));
            cselectorButtons = new JFrame();
            logo = new JLabel("SoccerKidz [REPLACE W/ COOL LOGO]");
            characterName = new JLabel("<Character Name>");
            logo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            logo.setFont(new Font(logo.getFont().getName(),
                    Font.HANGING_BASELINE, 50));
            characterName.setFont(new Font(characterName.getFont().getName(),
                    Font.HANGING_BASELINE, 50));
            cselectorButtons.add(logo);
            cselectorButtons.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            cselectorButtons.setContentPane(label);
            cselectorButtons.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            characterName.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
            characterName.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            cselectorButtons.add(characterName);
            logo.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
            logo.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
            cselectorButtons.add(logo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            cselectorButtons.pack();
            cselectorButtons.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            cselectorButtons.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new CharacterSelector();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't remove the "extends JFrame" line as I would receive a few errors from my constructor (you can see the code in the constructor in the code above). Secondly I've changed the positioning to what you recommended. Here is my new two lines of code.            cselectorButtons.add(logo, BorderLayout.NORTH); and             cselectorButtons.add(characterName, BorderLayout.CENTER); , however now neither appear.  I apologies for my quite ridiculous questions, my knowledge in GUI's is only a week old.

Comment: That's the whole point I'm getting at. You have a class frame, for which you do `this.someMethod()`, such as `this.setVisible()`. But you already have another instance of another frame where you `otherFraem.setVisible()`. You don't need the class frame. So when you remove the `extends JFrame`, remove all the `this.someMethod` because they are referring to the class JFrame.

Comment: ahh I see, it now works. However my other problem is sadly still not resolved. When I changed all the positioning to only two lines of code (cselectorButtons.add(logo, BorderLayout.NORTH); and cselectorButtons.add(characterName, BorderLayout.CENTER);) nothing appeared on the GUI. Here is my new code if you would like to check it out : http://pastie.org/9336695. I would like to thank you once again for your patience in trying to help me, I truly do appreciate it.

Comment: See my **UPDATE** I can't really spot any major differences from my code and yours. Maybe you can find it. But my code works. Just tested it

Comment: Thank you very much it works! I just have one last question. What's the difference between these two codes?                                  This is the code I put in the main class: characterSelector character = new characterSelector();                                                And here is the code you used :     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               new characterSelector();
            }
        });                                                            Both work fine, however I've seen your code more often. Thank you once again!

Comment: With my code, basically you are running your application in Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). All swing apps should be run this way. Please see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details. Also if this answer helped solve your problem, don't forget to accept it (by ticking the check mark). Glad I could help