# GUI: JButton Covering almost the entire screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

I have encountered a problem whilst working the `JFrame`'s, and JButtons. I am trying to center my `JButton`, however when I do so, it covers almost the entire screen. Any idea's on what's causing this?

Here is a picture on how it looks :

[image]

And here is my code :

```
package character;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Niknea on 6/28/14.
 */
public class characterSelector{


    JFrame  cselectorButtons, clogo;

    JLabel logo, characterName, label;

    JButton male, female;


    public characterSelector(){

        this.createCharacterSelector();

    }


    public void createCharacterSelector() {

        try {
            label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass()
                    .getResource("/resources/Grass_Background.jpg"))));
            cselectorButtons = new JFrame("SupremeSoccer");
            logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/Character_Selector_Image.png"))));
            characterName = new JLabel("<Character Name>");
            characterName.setFont(new Font(characterName.getFont().getName(),
                    Font.HANGING_BASELINE, 50));

            /*
            Buttons
             */

            male = new JButton("Male");


            ////******************////
            //// END OF BUTTONS  ////
            ////****************////
            cselectorButtons.add(logo);
            cselectorButtons.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            cselectorButtons.setContentPane(label);
            cselectorButtons.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            cselectorButtons.add(logo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
         cselectorButtons.add(male, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            cselectorButtons.pack();
            cselectorButtons.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            cselectorButtons.setVisible(true);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea's on what's causing this?

This is the default behaviour of `BorderLayout`.  The component at the `CENTER` position will occupy the maximum amount of space the is available from the parent component, when the other (`NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, `WEST`) positions have been taken into account

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you might consider creating another `JPanel` (set it's `opaque` state to `false` so it's transparent) and use something like `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` instead.

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for some more ideas

**Updated**

So based on your [linked code](http://pastie.org/9339159), I changed

```
part2 = new JPanel();
```

to

```
part2 = new JPanel(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
```

And got...

[image: Get it on]

**Updated with additional example**

Start by breaking down your requirements into individual containers and focus on the layout requirements for each individual, then build them all back into a single container.

This will make changing them later much easier and also make controlling them much easier...

[image: Grass]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ExampleLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExampleLayout();
    }

    public ExampleLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private HeaderPane header;
        private ScorePane score;
        private CharacterSelectionPane characterSelection;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JLabel background = new JLabel();

            try {
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Grass.jpg"));
                background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            add(background);

            background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            header = new HeaderPane();
            score = new ScorePane();
            characterSelection = new CharacterSelectionPane();

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            background.add(header, gbc);
            background.add(score, gbc);
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            background.add(characterSelection, gbc);
        }
    }

    public class HeaderPane extends JPanel {

        public HeaderPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Character Selection");
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 48f));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label);
            setOpaque(false);
        }

    }

    public class ScorePane extends JPanel {

        public ScorePane() {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("[-][-[]-][-]");
            label.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            add(label);
            setOpaque(false);
        }

    }

    public class CharacterSelectionPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton btMale;
        private JButton btFemale;
        private JTextField tfName;
        private JButton btContinue;

        public CharacterSelectionPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            btMale = new JButton("Male");
            btFemale = new JButton("Female");
            btContinue = new JButton("Continue");
            tfName = new JTextField(10);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(btMale, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(btFemale, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(tfName, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(btContinue, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I've had a bit of issue's in the past involving centering an object using JPanel. Would I be required to do that? Or just center the JPanel? Also, should I be creating a new frame like a main one, or is the first one ok to be the "main" one? Thanks again.

Comment: Use the `JPanel` instead of the button, this will be added to the `CENTER` position of the `JLabel`, but, so long as it's transparent, you won't even know it's there.  Something like `GridBagLayout` will then allow you to add components which will be positioned around the center of the container (the panel).  If you need to switch between views, you might consider using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) as well

Comment: Do you by any chance know a good guide I can check out about all of this? Thanks.

Comment: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: @Niknea you already got the guide in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24472525/2587435). Are you actually going to look at it this time?

Comment: I have indeed looked into a good chunk of the docs, and will finish it after I finish typing this question. I've managed to make it work, however the button isn't fully "centered" . Here is how it looks, http://imgur.com/Lj6JsPx, and here is my code http://pastie.org/9339159. I'll finish up the docs to see if it explains a fix, if not maybe you can solve it? Once again I apologies for my lack of knowledge involving creating GUI's. Thanks again.

Comment: It looks like you're still using the default layout manager for `JPanel` instead of using something like `GridBagLayout`

Comment: Alright, I'm really really really close to figuring this out. I've centered it. However now it only shows one button. I remembered when pesskillet said when two buttons are located in the same place it will be overrided. So I changed locations. Yet only the male button is in the center, the female button is no where to exists. Here is my code :  http://pastie.org/9339228. Thanks again.

Comment: First of all `GridBagConstraints.WEST` isn't used for filling, but for anchoring.  Second of all, try using `g.gridx++;` instead then add your next button

Comment: Thank you very much it finally works! I have one last question, how would I go along putting another component under the buttons? Is there some sort of method like \n? Thanks again, and once again my apologies for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Either place it in the `SOUTH` position of the `BorderLayout` or simply added to the next grid position under the buttons

Comment: How would I go along adding it to the next grid position? As assuming I can't do the same as I did before with the g.gridx++;, and if I set the position to SOUTH wouldn't that put the component at the very bottom?

Comment: `gridy` would be the property you're looking for, you'd need to reset the `gridx` position and possible supply a `gridwidth` value as well.  And yes, the `SOUTH` position would be place at the very bottom, like the header is at the top

Comment: Hey mad, my apolgies for bugging you again, but I encoutred a problem with the positioning. When I edit the y, the text wont go down. I would like the yellow text at the top to go down. Here is a picture: http://prntscr.com/3xwez4, and here is the code: http://pastie.org/9339414. Once again extremely sorry for bugging you again, and thanks again.

Comment: You can't add multiple components to the same position within `BorderLayout`

Comment: However I've created another JPanel for that JLabel. Am I only allowed to create one BorderLayout per gui?

Comment: No, you can have as many `BorderLayout`s as like, but only one per container...but you added `part3` to the `NORTH` position of the same container as the log; `cselectorButtons.add(part3, BorderLayout.NORTH);`

Comment: Ahh I see what your saying, the reason I set it north was because when it was in the panel named part2 that was located in the center, it would only go up to a certain extent. So where would you recommended me to position the image before I push it to the middle?

Comment: You could try using `GridBagLayout` as I did, or start with an outer panel with `BorderLayout`, to which you add the logo, then an inner pane with a `BorderLayout` onto which you add everything else and put this at the `CENTER` of the outer panel

Comment: I've changed it up a bit, created a main panel, and parts to it. However it still doesn't work. The characterName doesn't appear at all. Here is my code : http://pastie.org/9341203. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `BoxLayout` or (easier) `GridBagLayout` for the bottom area, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181197/418556).

[image]